# What is the difference between this.click() and $(this).click()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

In the end, I have decided that this isn't a problem that I particularly need to fix, however it bothers me that I don't understand why it is happening.

Basically, I have some checkboxes, and I only want the users to be able to select a certain number of them.  I'm using the code below to achieve that effect.

```
$j( function () {
    $j('input[type=checkbox].vote_item').click( function() {
        var numLeft = (+$j('#vote_num').text());
        console.log(numLeft);
        if ( numLeft == 0 && this.checked ) {
            alert('I\'m sorry, you have already voted for the number of items that you are allowed to vote for.');
            return false;
        } else {
            if ( this.checked == true ) {
                $j('#vote_num').html(numLeft-1);
            } else {
                $j('#vote_num').html(numLeft+1);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And when I was testing it, I noticed that if I used:

```
$j('input[type=checkbox]').each( function () {
    this.click()
});
```

The JavaScript reacted as I would expect, however when used with:

```
$j('input[type=checkbox]').each( function () {
    $j(this).click()
});
```

It would actually make the counter count UP.

I do realize that it isn't the most secure way to keep count using the counter, however I do have server side error-checking that prevents more than the requisite amount from being entered in the database, that being the reason that I have decided that it doesn't actually need fixing.

Edit:  The `$j` is due to the fact that I have to use jQuery in `noConflict` mode...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that counter is going up gave me the clue that there is a link between checked attribute, which you are using, and firing the click event manually.

I searched Google for 'jquery checkbox click event raise' and found this link, where author faces the exact same problem and the workaround he used.

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1525-jQuery-s-Event-Triggering-Order-Of-Default-Behavior-And-triggerHandler-.htm

On a side note, I think you can simplify your code further:

```
$j('input[type=checkbox].vote_item').click( 
function() 
{
    var maxNumberOfChoices = 5;

    //get number of checked checkboxes. 
    var currentCheckedCount = $j('input[type=checkbox].vote_item :checked');

    if(currentCheckedCount > maxNumberOfChoices)
    {
        //It's useful if you show how many choices user can make. :)
        alert('You can only select maximum ' + maxNumberOfChoices + ' checkboxes.');
        return false;
    }

    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 6):

$(this) contains a jQuery wrapper (with lots of functions) whereas this is solely the DOM object.

Comment: That I understand, however...what exactly is the difference between the functions?  And does jQuery change the functionality of other DOM events when triggered through a jQuery-wrapped element?

Answer (score 3):

`this.click()` calls the browser DOM method [`click()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-html.html#ID-2651361).

`$(this).click()` calls the jQuery method [`click()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/click#click.28_.29), which does more than just call the browser method: see the implementation of the function [`trigger`](http://dev.jquery.com/browser/trunk/jquery/src/event.js#L192) for details.